# Create a java application that displays the sum of the digits of a number

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and I'm currently learning while, do while and for loops. I want to create an application that displays the sum of the digits of a number using these concepts but I have no idea how. I previously created an application that displayed ONLY THE DIGITS of a number. Here it is.

```
int digit;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    digit = input.nextInt();
} while (digit <= 0);
input.close();

String sdigit = digit + "";
for (int i = 0; i < sdigit.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(sdigit.charAt(i));
}
```

I'm trying to think of a possible way to expand on this program, but I have no idea why. Once again, this program is not what I need, what I need is somehow to sum the digits of a number using for or while loops. Thank you!

Comment: You are getting the integer multiple times (multiple numbers). Try reading in the integer once (not in the loop). Then you do some logic in the loop to get the individual digits.

Comment: this will keep on asking the user for input unless and until you enter a non numeric number and break the program ( because you are getting `nextInt()` )

Comment: @mrid No, it stops looping if a positive number is entered.  That's what the `while (digit <= 0)` is for.

Comment: @DM thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: why is the i in 
sum = sum + (sdigit.charAt(i) - '0');
being read as an error by my program?

Comment: the error is stating that the "string index out of range: 3" 
i have no idea what is happening

Comment: A { is missing in your for loop (after for (int i = 0; i < sdigit.length(); i++))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not much code has to be added for summing the digits :

First solution : using a substract with '0' character

```
int digit;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    digit = input.nextInt();
} while (digit <= 0);
input.close();

String sdigit = digit + "";
int sum=0;       

for (int i = 0; i < sdigit.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(sdigit.charAt(i));
    sum = sum + (sdigit.charAt(i) - '0');
}

System.out.println("Sum is : "+sum);
```

Second solution : using Integer.parseInt which converts String to int :

```
int digit;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    digit = input.nextInt();
} while (digit <= 0);
input.close();

String sdigit = digit + "";
int sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < sdigit.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(sdigit.charAt(i));
    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(sdigit.subString(i,i+1));
}

System.out.println("Sum is : "+sum);
```

Comment: I tried using the idea of adding the sdigit.charAt(i) to the sum
I did sum += sdigit.charAt(i) but it didnt work. Can you explain why I have to add a - 0? Thank you. Other than that, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: sdigit.charAt(i) is type of Character not an integer. You cannot add directly a char and and int. The sdigit.charAt(i) minus '0' allows to do the conversion

Comment: A character, is behind, a character code : a number representing the character. The digits characters are order in the same ordered than the natural digit order (the '1' is +1 in character code from '0', the '2' is +2 etc...), so if you do character digit minus '0' character, you got its index

Comment: One more question. The i variable in the second last line of code sum = sum + (sdigit.charAt(i) - '0'); is displaying an error nefore I even run the program. When i press it, it states that I need to initialize i, which I have already done in the for loop. Why is this happening?

Comment: Nevermind i just needed to erase the sysout line before it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
int digit;
System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
number= Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

int sum=0;
int currDigit = 0;
while( number / 10 > 0) {
    currDigit  = number % 10; //fetching last digit
    System.out.println(currDigit);
    sum = sum + currDigit;
    number = number / 10;
}
```